# Select the first span tag form a div class

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
  <div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
                            <span>13,978</span>
                            <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+2.3% 
                            </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

                        <div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">
                            <span>99,585</span>
                            <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+0.6% 
                        </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>
  <div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
                            <span>12121</span>
                            <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+2.3% 
                            </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

                        <div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">
                            <span>99,222</span>
                            <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+0.6% 
                        </span><span>)</span>                       

</div>
```

I tried the code below:

```
text=[]
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
TicketNuber=soup.find_all("div")
for div in TicketNuber:
        text.append(div.find("span"))
it prints out:[
 '13,978',
 '13,978',
 '99,585',
 '12,121'
 '12,121'
 '99,222'
 ]
```

Not sure why the first number will print out twice. I only want the number 
['13,978','99492','12,121','99,222']. there is no duplicate number in the same tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may do the job:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

document = '''
<div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
  <span>13,978</span>
  <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+2.3% 
  </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

<div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">
  <span>99,585</span>
  <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+0.6% 
  </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

<div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
  <span>12121</span>
  <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+2.3% 
  </span><span>)</span>                       
</div>

<div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">
  <span>99,222</span>
  <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+0.6% 
  </span><span>)</span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(document, "lxml")

for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(div.find("span").text)
```

Output:

```
13,978
99,585
12121
99,222
```

Clearly, there is some discrepancy from your HTML document and mine which must come down to the snippet you've taken not matching the actual document, which you can print and post using `print(soup)`. You've also only posted part of your code (not an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I'll need to see the whole story to help further.

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(div.find("span").text)  and i got the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Thanks for your help!

Comment: OK--I plugged your HTML in verbatim and it works, so can you post whatever `browser.page_source` is or the URL you're scraping or the code you're using? Clearly, there's some discrepancy.

Comment: Hi Gorlen, Thanks for your reply. It works. However, I can printing out multiple same numbers now. not sure why.

Comment: Like I said, I can't do anything without more information than you've given. You need to post your code, aURL you're scraping, and/or the actual HTML you're talking about for me to be able to diagnose your problem.

Comment: sorry i can't post link. Need credentials to login. Basically when i use this the code above, it will print out the first number twice. I guess i made some mistake about the for loop.

Comment: I doubt that--a loop is a loop. It seems more likely that there are two elements with the same contents. If you need to login, login and copy the DOM or the output of your `print(browser.page_source)`, post it, and I'll have an answer for you, otherwise I'm left to guess.

Comment: <div class="ticket_last_24 report_table_right">
       <span>69</span>
       <span>(</span><span class="change_increase">+9.5%</span><span>)</span>      </div>

      <div class="ticket_last_week report_table_right">
       <span>466</span>
       <span>(</span><span class="change_decrease">-13%</span><span>)</span>      </div>
This is what i print out the browser.page_source, when i use the code for div in soup.find_all("div"):
    print(div.find("span").text), it print out : 69,69,+9.5%,466,466,-13%